# How to take the item from string and use it as a value

Tags: python, string, data-structures, types, linear-regression

I have a string and I need to use this string to fit a model. However when I try try to do this, of course it raises an error which can be seen below. How can I use this string to fit the model?

```
import re
best_model_final = 'LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True,normalize=True)'
best_model_name = re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", best_model_final )
best_model_name.fit(X.iloc[:-1], y.iloc[:-1])

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the string into a Python object, ie do

```
best_model_final = 'LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True,normalize=True)'
best_model_name = re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", best_model_final )
best_model = eval(best_model_name)
best_model.fit(X.iloc[:-1], y.iloc[:-1]
```

See documentation of `eval()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: But in this particular example it seems that the `re.sub()` call is unnecessary, since the whole string is already a python expression defining a model

Comment: When I apply the eval method, my string transforms into "LinearRegression(normalize=True)", it deletes fit_intercept=True part. Do you have any idea for the reason behind this case?

Comment: This is probably because `fit_intercept=True` is the dafault value for this argument, while `normalize=True` is not, so it only shows the parameters that are different from the default (but they are passed correctly)